# Use of function overriding in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, inheritance

I am trying to learn from other contracts and have seen an example which I do not understand. In this example a first contract is defined as follows, but it seems that the functions do not actually do anything. (BTW this is the etherdelta smartcontract...)

```
contract Token {

  //part of the contract functions goes here

  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {}

  // other part of the contract functions goes here
}
```

Then, a new contract is defined, which seems to refer to the first contract:

```
contract StandardToken is Token {

  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
    //Default assumes totalSupply can't be over max (2^256 - 1).
    //If your token leaves out totalSupply and can issue more tokens as time goes on, you need to check if it doesn't wrap.
    //Replace the if with this one instead.
    if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value > balances[_to]) {
    //if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0) {
      balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
      balances[_to] += _value;
      Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
      return true;
    } else { return false; }
  }
```

Can anybody explain me please what this does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contract standard Token is derived from Token. This concept is called [inheritance](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#inheritance).

Solidity as a contract-oriented programming language allows inheritance that enables new contracts to take on the properties of existing contracts.

> Functions can be overridden by another function with the same name and
>   the same number/types of inputs.

Here the `transfer` function in Token is overridden in it's derived contract StandardToken.

This is useful for polymorphism, where you can define different concrete implementations for different uses, but still give a same interface for all.

In the above posted code, contract `token` defines a function `transfer` but doesn't implement the behavior of it. But all the other types of tokens (including `standardtoken` here and may be some other) can be made to derived from `token` contract and inside them they implement the behavior specific to them accordingly. Users will have to only know there is a function called `transfer` to use any type of token contracts derived from `token` thus providing a common interface.

Refer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) as well.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick answer, which explains it perfectly. What I have not understood though is why they do it like this.

Comment: that's for the purpose of  polymorphism basically, that allows different concrete implementations of the same abstract interface.

Comment: Many thanks. No, I am just a hobby programmer and I have not come across this concept before.

Comment: No ;-) But I will try to look it up and see what it means.

Comment: you are welcome , refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used) as well :)

Comment: What happens to inherited functions modifiers? Do they get inherited too?